# Angularjs app.run doesn't load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem with app.run(). In the main page app.run() is working. When I click to the menu button Events and in the page events.html app.run() doesn't work. But when I reload this page app.run() is working. I don't know what to do. Pages main.html and events.html are in the ngView, menu also is in the ngView.
controller.js

```
afroEarthApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
      .when('/',{
        templateUrl:'template/home.html',
        controller:'afroEarthMainCtrl'
      })
      .when('/events',{
        templateUrl:'template/events.html',
        controller:'eventsCtrl'
      })
      .when('/sites/:niche', {
        templateUrl:'template/single.html',
        controller:'SingleCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      })
}]);
afroEarthApp.controller('afroEarthMainCtrl',['$scope','$http','$location','$cookies', '$rootScope', '$route', function($scope, $http, $location, $cookies, $rootScope, $route) {
...some code...
}]);

afroEarthApp.controller('eventsCtrl',['$scope','$http','$location','$cookies', '$rootScope', '$route', function($scope, $http, $location, $cookies, $rootScope, $route) {
...some code...
}]);

afroEarthApp.run(['$log', '$rootScope', '$route', function ($log, $rootScope, $route) {
    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function ($rootScope, $route) {
...some code...
})
}]);
```

home.html

```
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#websites">Lifestyle sites</a></li>
            <li><a class="page-scroll" href="stories">Success Stories</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/events" data-target="#events" target="_self">Events</a></li>
            <li><a class="page-scroll" ng-href="http://{{singleNiche.url}}.afroearth.com/login/">Login</a></li>
            <li class="other-countries">
                <a href="#">
                    {{singleNiche.country}}<img src="{{singleNiche.countryFlag}}"><i class="icon-caret-down"></i>
                </a>
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="country in singleNiche.countries"><a ng-click="setCountry(country.url)" >{{country.name}}</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Can you hepl me please.

Comment: run block is executed only once at the start of your app, hence it works on reload.

Comment: Well,
That's the way angular run :)

The run function is called only when angular is loaded.

Comment: Ok. What I should to do? In the app.run code for all controllers.

Answer (score 1):

add the following in your **app.run**

```
 $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, nextLocation, currentLocation) {
//your code here
});
```

This function will be call on every url change.

Comment: `afroEarthApp.run(['$log', '$rootScope', '$route', function ($log, $rootScope, $route) {
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, nextLocation, currentLocation) {
        $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function ($rootScope, $route) {` I added like this, but still doesn't work.